# bundling script files in web application with asp.net optimization framework

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I'm using following code to bundle my web application scripts, but it does not generate bundled script

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle("~/miniscripts/");
        bundle.Include(
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.old_browsers_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.site_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.list_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_accessibleList_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.jquery_tip_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.highchart.highstock_src_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.highchart.modules.exporting_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.calendar.calendar_setup_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.AdminSkin.js.live_control_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.linq_js_ver_3_0_1_beta2.linq_js,
          "~"+  Paths.Scripts.moment.moment_min_js
            );

        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
```

What i'm missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, i dont know why `Scripts.Render("~/miniscripts/")` does not renders scripts.
I've wrapped it with Response.Write and the problem solved.

```
  Response.Write(Scripts.Render("~/miniscripts/"));
```

Comment: Scripts.Render returns you an IHtmlString, you can just do this as well: <%: Scripts.Render("~/miniscripts/") %>

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you are using the 1.0.0 package, you probably want to be using

```
new ScriptBundle("~/miniscripts/");
```

Otherwise your Bundle is not doing any minification, its just bundling all the script files together. Then in your page, you will need to add:

```
Scripts.Render("~/miniscripts");
```

For the bundle reference to get rendered out. You should also check out the tutorial here: [Optimization Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using the online bundle and minification version.

First you have to add JsMinify when creating the bundle so asp.net knows how to minifiy your files

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle("~/miniscript", typeof(JsMinify));
```

And then you have to add a script reference to your page

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/miniscript") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle("~/miniscript", typeof(JsMinify)); is deprecated and in AspNet.Web.Optimization [link]http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization optimization version we just provide virtualPath.